# delaying the python bs4 html loading to load the html of the page of the website to extract it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

m using this code for scrapping some data from the link https://website.grader.com/results/www.dubizzle.com

The code is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta

import MySQLdb
import re
import pdb
import sys
import string

def getting_urls_of_all_pages(): 
    url_rent_flat='https://website.grader.com/results/dubizzle.com'
    every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(url_rent_flat) 


def every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(url):

    htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

    print soup

    Sizeofweb=""
    try:

        Sizeofweb= soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': ".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0"}).text
        print Sizeofweb.get_text().encode("utf-8")

    except StandardError as e:
        error="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print error

getting_urls_of_all_pages()
```

The part of the html which i am extracting is as below

Snap: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dwbaiyizwa36m6/5.PNG?dl=0

Code:

```
<div class="result-value" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1">
<span data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0">1.1</span>
<span class="result-value-unit" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.1">MB</span>
</div>
```

Problem: Problem is that the website takes around 10-15 seconds to load the html source file which has the tags which i want to extract as mentioned in the code.

When the code uses the line htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(url).read() to load the html of the page, I think it loads html of preload of the link which is there before 10-15 seconds.

How can i make a pause in the code and let it load the data after 15+ seconds so the right html with the tags i want to extract loads in the program?

someone recommended me to use selenium. Here is the code but not sure whether if can be integrated in my code and serves the purposes

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(baseurl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and that is why you are not getting the expected response withe `urllib`. Selenium is a good solution to that problem.

For selenium use the following:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(baseurl)
time.sleep(15)
html = driver.page_source
soup  = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: Am i missing something?

Comment: It looks like you managed to install selenium, but the most recent version of selenium (or maybe firefox?) splits out the driver and you need to install it seperately. Download it [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), extract and place the binary somewhere on your [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).